# Fade transition for jquery image swap

Tags: javascript, jquery, attributes

I'm somewhat new to jquery and I have this working function that swaps images on the hover of a list element.  I am trying to add a fadeOut and fadeIn but its not working. The image fades out, but it doesn't get the correct path for the new image.
This is the working script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var path = 'images/';
    $('.menu-child').hover(function() {
        var newimage = $(this).attr('data-path') + '.jpg';
        $('.swap > img').attr('src', path + newimage)
    });
});
```

This is what I tried for fade effect (and a couple of variations, none of which I could get to work):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var path = 'images/';
    $('.menu-child').hover(function() {
    var newimage = $('.menu-child').attr('data-path') + '.jpg';
        $('.swap > img').fadeOut(function() {
            $('.swap > img').attr('src', path + newimage).fadenIn();
        });
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<section class="submenuWrapper">
    <ul class="twinsub">
        <li class="twinmultisub twinleft">
             <ul>
                  <li class="menu-child" data-path="menu-interior"><a href="#"><span>Interior Painting</span></a></li>
                  <li class="menu-child" data-path="menu-exterior"><a href="#"><span>Exterior Painting</span></a></li>
             </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="twinmultisub twinimg">
             <section class="swap">
                 <img src="images/menu-exterior.jpg" />
             </section>
        </li>   
    </ul>
</section>
```

Comment: I see a typo there at `fadenIn`

Comment: that was mostly it!  You would think Dreamweaver would catch that for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There we a couple of things.

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var path = 'images/';
  $('.menu-child').hover(function() {
    var newimage = $(this).attr('data-path') + '.jpg';
    $('.swap > img').fadeOut(function() {
      $(this).attr('src', path + newimage).fadeIn();
    });
  });
});
```

Working Example: https://jsfiddle.net/sabrick/fudLgqxs/3/

You'll probably be able to figure out why it works now on your own, but let me know if you'd like any additional details.

Comment: so the only difference (other than my silly typo on 'fadeIn') is using 'this' for the element selector?  Isn't 'this' just a shortcut to select the same element that I am already selecting?  I just corrected the typo first and it still didn't work until I used 'this' like you did here.  I don't get that.  I actually was using 'this' on my very first attempt but it wasn't working (most likely due to the typo I didn't see) so I went to the full element name.  Unbelievable a typo cost me many hours of ripping my hair out!

Comment: Now that it's working well with this code, do you know if there is a way to modify this so that nothing happens when the mouse leaves the list item?  right now it fades out and in the image again.  I would like it to just leave the current image there.  I updated [your fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MilkyTech/m89tybcf/1) with full paths to the images.

Comment: ok fixed that by changing `hover` to `mouseenter` [new fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MilkyTech/m89tybcf/7/).  Now I need to get it to do nothing on `mouseenter` if the correct image is already there.

Comment: Here's that fix: https://jsfiddle.net/sabrick/dtr4kw6m/4/

And yes, my use of 'this' is just selecting the exact same element. You should try to use 'this' rather than selectors wherever possible; when you use a selector, it causes the script to search through the DOM for the element (rather costly), while the function exposes the 'this' context for free.

Comment: yeah, I already fixed it with a similar `if` statement: `if(path + newimage != ($('.swap > img').attr('src')))`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample with appropriate comments

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var path = 'images/';
    $('.menu-child').hover(function() {
        var newimage = $(this).attr('data-path') + '.jpg';
        if(newimage != (path + $('.swap > img').attr('src'))){
            /*if the current image being displayed is not the same
            as the data-path of the hovered element.
            This prevents it from running even when the image should
            not be changing
            */
            $('.swap > img').fadeOut(0);
            //first fade out the current image
            $('.swap > img').attr('src', path + newimage);
            //then change the path when it is not visible
            $('.swap > img').fadeIn(500);
            //then fade in the new image with the new path
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: this kinda works but not quite.  it weirdly brings the new image in twice. See it in action in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MilkyTech/m89tybcf/5/)